# For Touch spells with a Concentration duration, do you need to keep touching your target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, concentration

The spell *Protection from Evil and Good* reads:

> Casting Time: 1 action
>
> Range: Touch
>
> Duration: Concentration up to 10 minutes

Do you only need to touch your target during the casting time or do you have to maintain physical contact to concentrate on the spell?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From "Range"

> Once a spell is cast it's effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell description says otherwise (PHB p203).

Thus no, you don't have to maintain contact (unless the spell says so) when casting a touch concentration spell, just like you don't have to remain in range to concentrate on other spells, as the range is *only* a limitation when the spell is cast, not when sustaining it.